# Exceptions in ionization energies of Oxygen and Nitrogen

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

We all know that it is difficult to remove an electron from atoms that are half-filled or fully filled. Thus they have higher ionization energy.

But today my teacher said that $N^{-3}$ has a lower ionisation potential than $O^{-}$. Can anyone help me ? Sorry if the question is dumb.

Comment: Well, the title isn't doing it any favors...

Comment: Why is nitrogen happy with 3 extra electrons flying around. In fact, no isolated -2 ion is stable. Many -1 ions are happy in isolation.

Comment: Atoms have ionisation potentials, and bare nitride anion doesn't even *exist*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionization_energy#Exceptions_in_ionization_energies

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect what is being asked.

Comment: Be aware N is aside of few others the exception, having negative electron affinity ( and more negative ones for the 2nd and 3rd electrons). $\ce{N^3-}$ is stable only in ionic nitrides, stabilized by strong energy of ionic lattice, like for $\ce{Mg3N2}$.

Answer (score -3):

I am not an inorganic chemistry specialist. But it seems like $\ce{N^3-}$ has a filled valence shell whereas $\ce{O^-}$ is missing one electron to close the shell. which is why this oxidation state is often found bound to hydrogen in the form of hydroxyl. So it might be possible that taking the extra electron from the oxygen mono anion might be easier.

Comment: You need to enclose `\ce{...}` inside math mode, i.e. `$\ce{...}$` (this differs from original LaTeX)